# What is the syntax to set the auto increment start value in schema.yml with Doctrine?

Tags: sql, postgresql, doctrine

I want to set the start value for auto increment on a column to 1000000 (to avoid conflicts with a legacy application), but can't find any documentation that tells me how.

Pretty standard table, here's what the relevant bit looks like:

```
User:   
  attributes:
    export: tables
  columns: 
    id:
     type: integer
     primary: true
     autoincrement: true
    code:
     type: string(6)
...
```

Comment: Do you have psql access to the db?

Comment: The autoincrement in postgreSQL is based on sequences, do you know the sequence name associated to the "id" column?

Comment: Yes, it's user_id_seq, but there's no reference to it in schema.yml so I'm assuming it was added automatically by postgresql.

Comment: If you have access to the database, it might be simpler (and faster) to just alter the sequence there.

Comment: That would be easier and faster, but to try to keep everything together, we were hoping we could just make all of the db design in the schema.yml file and not have to touch the db at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to acomplish this would be the creation of a Doctrine Migration. There you are able to set the value of the sequence table to the value you want. Migrations are easy to use (http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en#migrations) and you can run it during your deployment process of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts since there seems no other way.

Can you set the default value of `id` to be 100000? I haven't tried this, but it might work.

Another option would be to have your install script insert a row with a `id` value of 100000. If necessary, it could remove it as well. This would move the autoincrement up to 100000.

Comment: Negative on both counts. I tried adding default: 1000000 to the id field and rows were still inserted starting at 1. I also tried adding a row with id 1000000 and removed it, and new entries started at 1.

Good ideas though.